# How can I send email to a facebook friend using his facebook id via fql or graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I send email to a facebook friend using his facebook id either via fql or graph api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly. You may be able to query that user's profile using the graph /user_id entry point, and if he's made his email address available to friends (via applications), you can retrieve it and send an email to it. It's incredibly flaky, because if you are looking to do this to multiple friends then you are relying on the friend having very open privacy settings; frankly, I'm not even sure if Facebook exposes email addresses through the API.

One work-around is to send an email to the person's facebook username @facebook.com. This will send them a Facebook message though, not an email.