# Need to send Email/Notification to Facebook User of iPhone app from server.

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have Facebook user's details Like  FBid, Fb user name on my server data base. I want to send email/Notification of this user on Facebook. How can I achieve this. It is very easy to send this via my iPhone app because Facebook access token is on my device but I want to send notification via Server. Please let me know How can I send this. Thanks

[What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

What I have already done : After R&D I found that "username@facebook.com" will work for send email to FB user, and it was working but after AWS setup its throwing mail bounce messages :(

http://www.facebook.com/help/224049364288051

[How can I send email to a facebook friend using his facebook id via fql or graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697919/how-can-i-send-email-to-a-facebook-friend-using-his-facebook-id-via-fql-or-graph)

[Sending Email to @facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137688/sending-email-to-facebook)

Comment: I was struggling with same problem if anyone ever faced this kind of problem please suggest thanks